# Maven Jenkins Plugin POMs missing for dependency information on JARs

Tags: maven, plugins, jenkins, dependencies, surefire

I have been trying to follow the tutorial here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial

I have spent about 7 hours on this now and finally decided to just ask and hope for a response.

I haven't edited the pom file at all from the create command. I am pretty sure I have my settings file correct. When I try to run or package the project though I get this:

```
    [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.9 is missing,            no dependency information available
    [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.9 is   missing, no dependency information available
    [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.0.9 is missing, no dependency information available
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 8.260s
    [INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 29 16:07:56 EST 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 41M/387M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.9:test (default-test) on project helloworld: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.9:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.9 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.9, org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.9, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.1: Failure to find org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.9 in http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of repo.jenkins-ci.org has elapsed or updates are forced ->
```

So I am assuming that it is supposed to be downloading these 3 jar files from the repositories I set up in the settings file... but it isn't. Is there any reason this would happen? Anything I can do to make it download these files? Or is it downloading them I am just not referencing them correctly somewhere? I'm pretty new to this so i could be completely off.

If it helps I have maven 3.0.4 and jdk 1.7.0_02. Everything else I have pretty much copy and pasted from the tutorial I think. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Something went probably wrong when you attempted to get the artefacts the first time, and now you are stuck because of a nasty maven bug. Maven might have created an empty folder in your local repository (.m2) and now thinks you already have the dependency. So you should check if this is what happened and, if so, deleted the folder.

See my answer here :

[Compiler error "archive for required library could not be read" - Spring Tool Suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857985/compiler-error-archive-for-required-library-could-not-be-read-spring-tool-su/10123184#10123184)

And you can also check why there was a problem in the first place. Do you access the following url with your browser ?

http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.9/