# error regarding reading of jar file

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am working on `JSP` and `Servlet` codes, but while running the code on server, I am getting error as

```
Archive for required library: 'C:/tools/softwares/apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x86/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/lib/ojdbc14.jar' in project 'asm' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
```

But I checked the `ojdbc.jar` file and it is present in the above given location.

Now I am not getting the error, why the jar file is not getting read?
Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sometimes it might just be a build issue in eclipse.. please refer to the questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093129/error-archive-for-required-library-cannot-be-read-or-is-not-a-valid-zip-file

Answer (score 1):

Check with this command

```
jar -tvf ojdbc14.jar .....
```

It will throw exception if jar is corrupt.