# Remove item from "Android Private Libraries" that is not in my project's libs folder

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

The scenario is this: Eclipse Juno, ADT 22.  The android project was created with a dependency on another Eclipse project (not an Android project, just a plain Java one) which exported a dependency on another library.  I have since removed the Java project from the list of dependencies, but the exported library dependency remains in the Android Private Libraries section of my project's build path, and I can't figure out how to remove it.

Any ideas?

(For reference, here's what the build path looks like:

[image: java build path dialog showing library]

The lib I want to get rid of is "simple-xml-2.6.2.jar", as I've switched to using JSON rather than XML and no longer need it.  The project "bincomodel" is no longer a dependency of this project; I removed it on the Projects tab.)

Comment: Is that library (.jar) present in your libs folder? In that case you can remove it from there, clean and build..

Comment: No, it is in the libs folder of the project that used to be a dependency but isn't any more.

Comment: Still can you just try to remove "simple-xml-2.6.2.jar" from the libs folder and see once.

Comment: It is still needed in the other project, so I cannot remove it from there.

Comment: How exactly have you removed "bincomodel" project. In your case it seems to be still attached with your project..

Comment: No, it's completely gone from the "Projects" tab. It's just left behind one of its dependencies in the "Libraries" tab -- I'm not sure how it even ended up there, to be honest, as I didn't think this was how the Libraries tab was supposed to work!

Comment: Possibly some cleaning is not working for you properly. Have you tried deleting you bin file and build again. Bin folder has "jarlist.cache". Else you may try creating new project and copying the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there are two places that the reference to the previous project needed to be deleted from, not just one.  It had to be taken out of both the "Projects" tab on "Build Path" and out of "Project References" in the project properties.

I believe that ADT is automatically including any jars in the "libs" folder of any project included in the "Project References" list, whether or not they are an exported dependency.  It also appears to link by default any jars that are in source folders, which eclipse standard doesn't do.

Comment: In Project -> Properties -> Build Config, when I removed the entire Android Private Libraries entry with that single .jar file already having been deleted, then that Android Private Libraries entry in build config was regenerated and that one .jar file was no longer there.

Comment: in my case I just delete the private libraries entry then restarted eclipse, when it was back it recreated this entry but without the jar causing problem.

Answer (score 16):

In my case I had removed a few .jar libs from the file system however the project had not updated after  doing SVN update.

Once I clicked on the libs folder the .jar flashed like it was there and then disappeared. So if you have this issue then try Right Click project > Refresh, this will update all folders with the underlying file structure.

Eclipse then auto updated to remove the files from the private libs build path.

A

Comment: Right Click on libs and Refresh worked for me, after I unsuccessfully tried re-starting eclipse, deleting private dependencies (which auto-generated), closing/opening project etc etc...

Answer (score 1):

exit eclipse and go to folder your_project/libs/. Delete file .jar you want.

Comment: The comments on the question show that the OP cannot remove the *.jar file from libs because it is needed for another project.

Comment: I also had to resort to deleting its proguard.cfg references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74728030/2597758

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could try to delete the unnecessary `dependency` from appropriate `.classpath`, afaik this path is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file project.properties in your filesystem and delete what you need. In my case I removed gridlayout_v7 deleting the second line:

```
# Project target.
target=android-15
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7
android.library.reference.2=../gridlayout_v7
```